# Unit test core data and a method with NSExpressionDescription

Tags: unit-testing, core-data

How do I make a unit test for the following piece code??

```
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
NSString *sumOfTotalPaidBySelf = @"sumOfTotalPaidBySelf";
expressionDescription.name = sumOfTotalPaidBySelf;
expressionDescription.expression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"@sum.moneyInMainCurrency"];
expressionDescription.expressionResultType = NSDoubleAttributeType;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MCPayment"];
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"payingPerson = %@", self];
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[expressionDescription];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchResult = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@: error fetching: %@", self, error);
    return nil;
}

return [[fetchResult firstObject] objectForKey:sumOfTotalPaidBySelf];
```

What I've learned so far is, that this code should work when querying a database that already contains data, which is stored on disk. However for the unit tests I use a persistentStoreType of NSInMemoryStoreType, which gets pre populated with some data during setup and that data still resides in the managedObjectContext.

This is the unit test I have.

```
MCSharedBill *tonightsBill = [MCSharedBill addSharedBillToContext:_context];
MCPerson *fred = [tonightsBill addPerson];
fred.firstName = @"Fred";
MCPerson *anna = [tonightsBill addPerson];
anna.firstName = @"Anna";
MCPayment *drinks = [tonightsBill addPayment];
drinks.payingPerson = fred;
drinks.money = @(10);
drinks.descriptionOfPayment = @"coffee";
NSNumber *totalPaidByFred = fred.totalSumPaid;
//    NSError *error = nil;
//    [_context save:&error]; 
//    XCTAssertFalse(error);
XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(@(10).doubleValue, totalPaidByFred.doubleValue, 0.001);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers.